# Dropdownlist in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have 3 dropdownlist which will have set of values from the database. In my page, I have different controls. I was planning to add this dropdownlist in a repeater control.

When a user selects a value, the value will be saved to the database, either by a save button inside the control or automatically.

Could you please let me know if this is possible? If yes, any code that can be shared would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  The trick is that the DataSource for the dropdownlists are separate than the DataSource of the Repeater.

Comment: I googled your title and the first hit had sample code: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/265.html

Comment: Thanks Steve. This is not what I wanted. I want a dropdownlist inside a repeater control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample code:

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 foreach (RepeaterItem ri in GeneralRepeater.Items)
        {
            switch (ri.ItemType)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:
                case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:

                    DropDownList GetValue = (DropDownList)ri.FindControl("GeneralDDL");
                    var sSelectedValue = GetValue.SelectedValue;

                    for (int index = 0; index <= PocDiagnoses.MAX_DIAGNOSIS; index++)
                    {
                        foreach (RepeaterItem ri1 in GeneralRepeater.Items)
                        {
                            int iItemIndex = ri1.ItemIndex;
                            DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)GeneralRepeater.Items[index].FindControl("GeneralDDL");

                            FirstPlanOfCare.Diagnoses.Diagnoses[index] = new PatientDiagnosis(myDDL.SelectedValue, new SynergyOnSetDate(new System.DateTime(Year, Month, Day)), "01/02/2011"); //Insert Diagnosis Value

                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        //Create
        Chart.AddPlanOfCare(FirstPlanOfCare);
```

}